# Sending JSON object to a service

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, testing, pycharm

I have written a simple service which, if sent the name of a football player, will return the team of said footballer. It's a learning project for myself.

I want to test the accuracy of my service.

I have made a JSON file with a list of footballers and their expected team. I want to send this off to my service and create a report to see how accurate I am.

The JSON looks like this -

```
{"Team": "Man Utd", "Players": "Ryan Giggs"}
{"Team": "Chelsea", "Players": "John Terry"}
.....
```

A simple start on my code -

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Service_Testing\\service_json.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

pprint(data)
```

Trying to load it in, however, I get the error -

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 47)
```

What is going wrong here? How can I load my JSON correctly? There are 46k lines in my json file which may be part of the issue !!

Comment: This is not valid json. Valid json should be one object or array, separated with colon. http://json.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this isn't valid JSON. You seem to have one JSON object per line; you could potentially load and parse those individually:

```
data = []
with open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Service_Testing\\service_json.json') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Although it would be better to fix the input file in the first place, so that it is correctly wrapped in an array with each object separated by commas.